# HTTPS on wordpress serves assets over http

Tags: wordpress, https

I've configured all my site to work over https.

https://bloginformatico.com

It's working but the assets are not loaded because are served over http.

Is there a way to change all assets to be served also over https?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to http://bloginformatico.com/wp-admin/ , go to Settings → General and check if both your Site Address and Wordpress Address start with https:// (I don't think they do). Change and save this.